# Waves plug-ins don't work on Mac's bootcamp?

Tags: waves, compatibility, mac, windows

I have the waves silver bundle and use it on my mac with pro tools no problem but I also have windows XP installed on my bootcamp side of the drive where I run Sonar 8.5 and Sound Forge. For some reason waves doesn't work even though it is compatible with windows XP. Why is this? I email waves and they just said bootcamp is not compatible! But its running windows so why? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your iLok drivers installed in Windows XP?  Go to ilok.com and make sure your ilok is recognized.

I ran bootcamp with Windows 7, Waves worked fine on both the Windows and Mac side.  I can't imagine it would be different with XP.

Comment: @Chuck Russom Thanks, you got it, my bootcamp partition wasn't recognizing my ilok. Its working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working.